# Jquery only works on page refresh

Tags: html, jquery

I have a jquery that adds a class to an element as the user scrolls and makes it fixed, based on the initial position of the element and the height of the header. (it gets fixed under the header but when scrolling back to the initial position it gets unfixed) for some reason it only works when I reload the page, so it gets fixed under the header but when scrolling back up it stays fixed to the header even past its initial position. Unless I reload the page, sometimes I need to reload multiple times for it to work properly

Following is my code:

```
 var fixunderHeader = $('.anchor-menu').offset().top; // get initial position of the element

    $(window).scroll(function () { // assign scroll event listener
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // get current position
        var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(); // get the height of the header element

        if (currentScroll >= fixunderHeader) {
            $(".anchor-menu").addClass("anchor-menu-grey").css({
                top: headerHeight + 'px' // set the top value to the height of the header
            });
            $(".background").addClass("back").css({
                top: headerHeight + 'px' // set the top value to the height of the header
            }); // add 'back' class to the element with class 'background'
        } else {
            $(".anchor-menu").removeClass("anchor-menu-grey").css({
                top: '' // remove the 'top' property
            });
            $(".background").removeClass("back").css({
                top: '' // remove the 'top' property
            }); // remove 'back' class from the element with class 'background'
        }
    });
```

I think the issue stems from this part of the code, because its not wrapped in another function, like $(document).ready(function() {, but when I tried wrapping the whole code in it, the code doesn't work at all:

```
var fixunderHeader = $('.anchor-menu').offset().top; // get initial position of the element
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: i mean... can't you just make them sticky?

Comment: Did you check [the browser's console](https://screenful.com/how-to-open-the-browser-console) for error messages? Use [the developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools) your browser has.

Comment: Making a minimal repoducible example that includes your HTML would help too.

Comment: @KevinB i cant make it sticky because I want the element to stay fixed when scrolling outside of its parent element as well

Comment: @KIKOSoftware weirdly enough I can't see it in the console because when I'm in developer mode I don't seem to have this issue, it's only when I'm in the regular browser

Comment: You seem to have a very weird problem. I cannot test it here, but I can give advice. It sometimes help to set an event listener after the whole page has finished rendering. Try to put your scroll event listener inside this code: `$(window).on('load', function() {  ... put code here ... });`. See: [Window: load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when I do that the code doesn't work at all

Comment: Again, check for errors in the console. Not working at all makes no sense.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when I removed other scripts that have nothing to do with this one that had errors in console and it did work but still buggy.
I am viewing my site through the extension Live server on VS code, that's where I have this issue, but I just noticed that when I view it locally it works fine. I guess the issue is with the extension as opposed to the code. Hopefully that's the case
Thanks for your help